# Google Script openById don't work?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

this is the code i wrote:

```
function importEventData(){
  var dFile = DocsList.getFileById("0Ar2YhVnsK7LLdGVrUFdpRUVQTHJ0aG1SVkp6V0JMMkE");
  var text = DocumentApp.openById("0Ar2YhVnsK7LLdGVrUFdpRUVQTHJ0aG1SVkp6V0JMMkE").editAsText().getText();
  return text;
};
```

The first line of the function works.
But unfortunatly at the second line the google compiler stops and say: "Document is missing.(maybe it is deleted.)"
Now I'm trying about several hours, search accross the web, but can't find the problem. The script has permissions to access my gDrive.
Although I tried to get the id from the dFile.getId() function. But this produces the same string and the same error.

Comment: Your document is actually a spreadsheet, so the DocumentApp, which can only access "Docs", has no access to it. (How do I know? I tried opening the doc by URL in my browser - the doc URL returned "not found", but a spreadsheet URL started the "ask for permission" dialog.)

Comment: Yes, it seems you should be using SpreadsheetApp.openById(). Also, while you're working on this, you should know that the DocsList service has been deprecated on Dec 11, 2014 and was shut off on April 20, 2015. https://developers.google.com/apps-script/sunset?hl=nl The Google Drive service replaces it. https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app

Answer (score 1):

```
var text = DocumentApp.openById("0Ar2YhVnsK7LLdGVrUFdpRUVQTHJ0aG1SVkp6V0JMMkE").getBody().editAsText().getText();
```

You need to add `.getBody()` before `.editAsText()` because `DocumentApp.openByID('id')` returns a document class object and the editastext method only applies to the body object. This is seen here in Google's documentation: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/document-app